# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: " "

Tags: sql, postgresql

Getting the following error in one of my views:

> SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: " "

I think it is because I have used the following COALESCE Command.

```
COALESCE(to_number(a_id, '999999999999999'::text), b_id::numeric) AS c_id,
```

- `a_id` is of type `text`
- `b_id` is of type `int4`

What changes should I make to make it working?

Comment: Your column appears to sometimes have spaces in it.  How would you like to handle this case?

Comment: The real question is: why are you storing numbers in a `text` column. You should really convert that to an `int` or `numeric` column

Answer (score 2):

Going by the error message, your `a_id` column appears to have values in it which are not numeric.  To flag such offending records you may try:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE NOT a_id ~ '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$';
```

As to how to handle such data, it is up to you.

Comment: I don't see any such value in my column

Comment: @AbHiNaVAgRaWaL Try my updated answer to find values which are not numeric (either integer or floating point).

Comment: Thanks. The new implementation works. However, what could be the way to handle such type of issue?

Comment: @ab: the solution to your problem is to not store numbers in text/varchar columns

Comment: Very handy, thank you @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

It looks like common Oracle->Postgres port bug. For Oracle `NULL` and empty string are +/- identical. So you can use empty string almost anywhere. Only Oracle has this feature - for any other SQL databases empty string is not `NULL`. For Postgres too. You cannot to cast empty string to numeric type in Postgres.

Note - is very tragic so your id column has numeric type, although there are numbers - it can be pretty slow with other negative impact.

Fix is easy when you know the reason:

```
COALESCE(to_number(CASE trim(a_id) WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE a_id END, '999999999999999'::text),
         b_id::numeric) AS c_id,
```

or if there are more white spaces, you can use

Anyway - when you migrate data from Oracle to Postgres, then is usually better to replace empty strings by NULLs immediately.

There is another performance issue - working with `numeric` type is slower than working with `int4` type. Using `numeric` type for identity is bad idea.

Comment: I can still see the same error even after using the case condition

Comment: @AbHiNaVAgRaWaL - yes, because you have a space, that is not empty string. I modified the reply

Comment: @AbHiNaVAgRaWaL - surely no, for this case, you should to replace space by empty string - but it is signal, so the input data are wrong and should be cleaned first

Comment: @PavelStehule . . . I would not describe Oracle's redefinition of `''` as `NULL` in violation of the standard a "feature".  "Bug" seems like a more apt description.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - it can be long discussion :). Surely, it is non conceptual feature. But it has some advantages, and probably it is very old feature, where CPU was much more slower and technical people created lot of dirty trick. I don't like it too, but this feature is here and we should to live with it :)

Comment: @PavelStehule . . . In Oracle's defense, it predates the standardization of SQL.  But that was more than 30 years ago.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - just one word "compatibility". If Oracle fix this issue, then one half of world will be broken.